# How to change output of Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, httprequest

I want to be able to get the results of Invoke-WebRequest and have my script print either "Failed" if the server was not reached or "Online" if it was reached.

This is what I'm doing to try to do that.

```
 $IW_Results = $Servers_to_Check | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ }

 $err = $IW_Results | ?{$_.gettype().Name -eq "ErrorRecord"}
 if($err){
 Write-Output "Failed"
 }
 else {
 Write-Output "Online"
 }
```

I was able to get the script to print "Online" if the server is reached. However when it can't be reached, my script wont print "Failed". Instead it will give me the error:

```
 Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
 At C:\Users\admin\Documents\VM-scripts\VM-tester.ps1:32 
 char:52
 + ... ts = $Servers_to_Check | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ }
 +                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 
 pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 
 ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

How can I get the script to print out "Failed" instead of this error message?

Also the `$Servers_to_Check` variable is multiple servers

Comment: look into using the `try/catch` structure. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **Try Catch**

```
$Servers_to_Check = "google.com", "asdasdf.asdfaa.sdf","yahoo.com"
$IW_Results = $Servers_to_Check | ForEach-Object { 
    try{
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ | Out-Null
        "Online"
    }catch{
        "Failed"
    }
}

$IW_Results
```

Comment: do you need to set the ErrorAction on the IWR call for that `catch` to work?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: you are quite correct! i broke down and [gasp! arg!] tested it ... [*grin*]